# CSS nth-child(odd): hover when hover:not used

Tags: css, css-selectors

Just wondering how I could get the odd rows to also not hover. I've tried every result I found on SO and nothing has worked. Disregard the box-shadow.

```
#list tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #fff;
}
#list td:empty {
    background: hsla(50, 25%, 60%, 0.7);
}
#list tr:hover:not(#firstrow), tr:hover td:empty {
    background: #ff0;
    pointer-events: visible;
}
#list tr:hover:not(#firstrow) {
    transform: box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

I know my onclick will not work so I left one of the odds open for you to see it in action. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwQpEN

Comment: You've forgotten to include other aspects of your code - you mention an onclick event, but there is no JavaScript or HTML to be seen.

Comment: adding nth-child(even) to my hover worked perfectly.

Comment: I've put my answer back - I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something prior to answering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an additional `:nth-child(even)` to each of your hover rules:

```
#list tr:hover:nth-child(even):not(#firstrow), tr:hover td:empty {
    background: #ff0;
    pointer-events: visible;
}
#list tr:hover:nth-child(even):not(#firstrow) {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

If `#firstrow` always refers to `tr:first-child`, then you can remove the `:not(#firstrow)` as well unless you need it for specificity.